# Three.js - can't render cube on Mapbox GL JS custom WebGL layer

Tags: javascript, three.js, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to render the cube using this example: [Add a 3D model](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model/).

Example work up to 117 version on three.js.
Since 118 version example doesn't work: cube disappears immediately after page refresh. I studied changelog and most noticeable change is that since v118 three.js uses WebGL2 as default render engine. So I changed code to use WebGL1, but still cube disappears.

```
  this.renderer = new THREE.WebGL1Renderer({
  canvas: map.getCanvas(),
  context: gl,
  antialias: true
});
```

Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/microspace/pen/YzqybVr) to reproduce the problem. (reload page to see the cube for a moment)

Comment: I had the same issue, it’s even better, if you want to LOL, add 2 cubes and it works. Honestly I think it’s a bug. 
If you are going to play hard with Mapbox and Three.js I’d recommend you to check [threebox](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox) out

Comment: Thank you, @jscastro! adding second cube solved the problem O_o. I'll definitely checkout threebox. What can you tell about maptalks?

Comment: It’s an amazing framework but I decided to go with mapbox because it’s also the core of Azure Maps and I found several serious issues with models in maptalks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, but it was resolved by replacing `renderer.state.reset()` in the `render()` function with `renderer.resetState()` which was introduced in r124 and improved in r126.

[Mapbox example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model/) has also been updated.